# Why the number of weights in simple RNN is more than the number of weights in GRU?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I have read that the number of (trainable) weights/parameters  are more in simple RNN compared to GRUs even though GRU also has gates present in it, can anyone explain? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide where you've read this? This will depend on a # of factors, this may be true in certain situations but not expected.